# PHP - Redisplay forms with valid values in fields and error messages where validation fails

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have created a PHP form to take 4  text fields name, email, username and password and have set validation for these. I have my code currently validating correctly and displaying messages if the code validates or not.
However, I would like for it to keep the correctly validated fields filled when submitted and those that failed validation to be empty with an error message detailing why.

So far I have the following code, the main form.php:

```
    <?php
    $self = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $self; ?>" method="post">
        <fieldset>
        <p>You must fill in every field</p>
        <legend>Personal details</legend>
            <?php
            include 'personaldetails.php';
            include 'logindetails.php';
            ?>
            <div>            
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Register" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <?php
    $firstname = validate_fname();
    $emailad = validate_email();
    $username = validate_username();
    $pword = validate_pw();
    ?>
```

My functions.php code is as follows:

```
<?php
function validate_fname() {
    if (!empty($_POST['fname']))    {
        $form_is_submitted = true;
        $trimmed = trim($_POST['fname']);
        if  (strlen($trimmed)<=150  && preg_match('/\\s/', $trimmed))   {
            $fname = htmlentities($_POST['fname']);
            echo "<p>You entered full name: $fname</p>";
        }   else    {
                echo "<p>Full name must be no more than 150 characters and must contain one space.</p>";
        }   }
        }

function validate_email() {        
    if (!empty($_POST['email']))    {
        $form_is_submitted = true;
        $trimmed = trim($_POST['email']);
        if  (filter_var($trimmed, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))   {
            $clean['email'] = $_POST['email'];              
            $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);

            echo "<p>You entered email: $email</p>";
        }   else    {
                echo "<p>Incorrect email entered!</p>";
        }   }   
        }

function validate_username() {
    if (!empty($_POST['uname']))        {
        $form_is_submitted = true;
        $trimmed = trim($_POST['uname']);
        if  (strlen($trimmed)>=5 && strlen($trimmed) <=10)  {
            $uname = htmlentities($_POST['uname']);
            echo "<p>You entered username: $uname</p>";
        }   else    {
                echo "<p>Username must be of length 5-10 characters!</p>";
        }   }   
    }

function validate_pw()  {
    if (!empty($_POST['pw']))   {
        $form_is_submitted = true;
        $trimmed = trim($_POST['pw']);
        if  (strlen($trimmed)>=8 && strlen($trimmed) <=10)  {           
            $pword = htmlentities($_POST['pw']);
            echo "<p>You entered password: $pword</p>";
        }   else    {
                echo "<p>Password must be of length 8-10 characters!</p>";      
        }   }
    }
?>
```

How can I ensure that when submit is pressed that it will retain valid inputs and empty invalid ones returning error messages.

Preferably I would also like there to be an alternate else condition for initial if(!empty). I had this initially but found it would start the form with an error message.

Lastly, how could I record the valid information into an external file to use for checking login details after signing up via this form?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What specific problem are you having? Which part of the data validation/repopulating is not working for you?  have you done any debugging to narrow down why it is not working? As it is, you have not shown any code at all that would populate value back into the form on error.

Comment: Just set the input value to html safe user input from post

Comment: Where's this code  `include 'personaldetails.php'; include 'logindetails.php';` ? Add this to the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1)` so you can identify where's the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a separate variable for errors, and not output error messages to the `input` field.

You could use `global` variables for this, but I'm not fond of them.

login.php

```
<?php 
$firstname = '';
$password  = '';
$username  = '';
$emailadd  = '';
$response  = '';
include_once('loginprocess.php');
include_once('includes/header.php);
//Header stuff
?>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");?>" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <p>Please enter your username and password</p>
    <legend>Login</legend>
        <div>
        <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fullname" value="<?php echo $firstname ?>" />
        </div>
        <div>
         <label for="emailad">Email address</label>
         <input type="text" name="email" id="emailad" value="<?php echo $emailadd; ?>"/>
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for="username">Username (between 5-10 characters)</label>
        <input type="text" name="uname" id="username" value='<?php echo $username; ?>' />
        </div>
        <div>            
        <label for="password">Password (between 8-10 characters)</label>
        <input type="text" name="pw" id="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" />
        </div>
        <div>            
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<?php
//Output the $reponse variable, if your validation functions run, then it
// will contain a string, if not, then it will be empty.
if($response != ''){
    print $response;         
}     
?>
//Footer stuff
```

loginprocess.php

```
//No need for header stuff, because it's loaded with login.php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){//Will only run if a post request was made.
    //Here we concatenate the return values of your validation functions.
    $response .= validate_fname();
    $response .= validate_email();
    $response .= validate_username();
    $response .= validate_pw();
}    
//...or footer stuff.
```

functions.php

```
function validate_fname() {
    //Note the use of global...
    global $firstname;
    if (!empty($_POST['fname']))    {
        $form_is_submitted = true;
        $trimmed = trim($_POST['fname']);
        if(strlen($trimmed)<=150  && preg_match('/\\s/', $trimmed)){
            $fname = htmlentities($_POST['fname']);
            //..and the setting of the global.
            $firstname = $fname;
            //Change all your 'echo' to 'return' in other functions.
            return"<p>You entered full name: $fname</p>";
        } else {
            return "<p>Full name must be no more than 150 characters and must contain one space.</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

I wouldn't suggest using includes for small things like forms, I find it tends to make a mess of things quite quickly. Keep all your 'display' code in one file, and use includes for functions (like you have) and split files only when the scope has changed. i.e your functions.php file deals with validation at the moment, but you might want to make a new include later that deals with the actual login or registration process.

Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php to find out about concatenating.

Comment: Have you replaced the 'echo' with 'return' ? Also your Sky Drive doesn't reflect the changes I've suggested so I don't know where to begin!

Comment: My problem really is that because if I use $_POST for the label for text fields then it doesn't let me clear the invalid inputs. But if I use variables for the text fields then upon submitting it displays the correct error messages but clears all the input data.

What I need is for it to keep validated input but clear the incorrect inputs - I need a way for it to declare the variables holding inputs as empty upon first running of register.php (otherwise the fields are filled with error messages) but not upon it updating the form. I know that this is where my error lies.

Comment: I declare the variables in register.php as:

  $fname = '';
  $email = '';
  $uname = '';
  $pw = '';

But then when the funtions are run and page updated it empties the values the variables gained through the functions.
If I use $POST then the text fields only hold what was entered regardless of it not validating.

Comment: Okay, I've added comments to your SkyDrive.

Comment: Hi again - I tried the changes you suggested but it does the same thing.

Comment: In essence my problem is the value labels of the text fields. everything else works, just at the moment because I declare the variables as '' at the start of register.php when the page updates it clears them again, whereas instead I'd like it to ignore that for later parts and just use the values the functions assigns to those variables when executed.

Comment: I've just downloaded your files, and made the changes I suggested, and it works. Though, you do need to remove my comment above `_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

Comment: Thank you - Checking now! :D

Comment: You are faaaaabulous! It works (Hallelujah!) Thank you sooo much! You have made my day! :D

Comment: Cool, click the answer toggle please. :-)

Comment: Hiya again - I've got it writing registration info to data.txt file correctly when all registration info validates. I'm now trying to get check login details & have written the following function:

Comment: function validate_logon() {
  global $uname, $pw, $toread, $userparts;
  $uname = htmlentities($_POST['uname']);
  $pw = htmlentities($_POST['pw']);
  $handle = fopen("data.txt", "r"); 
        while (!feof($handle)){
         $toread = fgets($handle);
         $userparts = explode(",","$toread");
   if (isset($userparts[2]) == $uname){
     if (isset($userparts[3]) == $pw)  {
     return "<p>You have successfully logged on</p>";
   }
   else {
     return "<p>Username and password do not match. Please try again.</p>";
   }
  } }
 }

Comment: Edit your post instead, I can't make out your code...Though `isset()` only returns `true` or `false`, it wont return the value of the variable your testing. Best off asking a new question.